# What is the difference between gross and net enterprise wide risk?

Tags: risk, basel

Reading a Basel paper on recommendations on internal economic capital models. One of the recommendations says members of the bank's board should be able to demonstrate understanding of the difference between

> gross (stand alone) and net enterprise wide (diversified) risk when
>   they define and communicate measures of the bank’s risk appetite on a
>   net basis

**Question:** Are they talking about a diversification benefit when aggregating risks firm wide ? 
(Also, I'm not sure if the terms are gross enterprise wide risk and net enterprise wide risk or gross risk and net enterprise wide risk)

The paper is [Range of practices and issues in economic capital frameworks](http://www.bis.org/publ/bcbs152.pdf), and below is the whole paragraph:

> Use of economic capital models in assessing capital adequacy . A bank
>   using  an economic capital model in its dialogue with supervisors,
>   should be able to  demonstrate how the economic capital model  has
>   been integrated into the business  decision making process in order to
>   assess its potential impact on the incentives  affecting the bank’s
>   strategic decisions about the mix and direction of inherent risks. 
>   The bank’s board of directors should also be able to demonstrate
>   conceptual  awareness and understanding of the gap between gross
>   (stand alone) and net  enterprise wide (diversified) risk when they
>   define and communicate measures of  the bank’s risk appetite on a net
>   basis.